# How strict should be interfaces (a good interface design)

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection

*I am not sure if this even fits on StackOverflow, or maybe rather on Programmers@StackExchange. If this should rather go there, let me know in a comment below and I will move it :)*

Anyway - back to the point. I have never done much programming using interfaces and Constructor/Property dependency injection etc. So I do know too much about it. I have been reading some articles though, mainly [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13831/Dependency-Injection-for-Loose-Coupling), and found this an interesting technique to make my software more flexible and testable.
So off I go and start refactoring an existing application (C#), and I come across a dilemma, which one of the 2 below choices is better:
**Choice 1** - minimum dependency requirements in a function. Leave some injection for constructor (implementation decision when using the interface)

```
public interface IDriver
{
    bool Start();
    bool Stop();
    bool Read(uint[] signal1, uint[] signal2);
}

public class MyDriver : IDriver
{
    public MyDriver(ISettings settings)
    {
        //remember ISettings in a local var
    }

    //interface implementation
}
```

**Choice 2** - all required dependencies in a function call.

```
public interface IDriver
{
    bool Start();
    bool Stop();
    bool Read(ISettings settings, uint[] signal1, uint[] signal2);
}

public class MyDriver : IDriver
{
    //implementation of the interface
}
```

Now the choice 2 might be wrong , right? because some implementations might actually not need the ISettings to work. The fact that my implementation of IDriver uses ISettings at the moment does not mean that it will in a year or so, so the logical approach would be to use method 1.

So my question would be: how strict should I make my interfaces, and how to not get mixed up between an interface and an implementation? I do not want the implementation to influence how I design my interfaces.
Also, does anyone know of good articles about the topic?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for responding to answers but -1 You need to upvote helpful answers (for lots of reasons), c'mon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces should be defined and owned by the clients that consume the interfaces. As [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices](http://amzn.to/19W4JHk) explain, **"clients […] own the abstract interfaces"** (chapter 11). Thus, if the client only *requires* this to work (your option 1):

```
public interface IDriver
{
    bool Start();
    bool Stop();
    bool Read(uint[] signal1, uint[] signal2);
}
```

then that should be the interface. Everything else is an **implementation detail**, and should go in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the book, I might actually buy it :)

Answer (score 0):

More than strictness, it is a question of contractual necessity.

Is ISettings contractually needed for your Read functionality? Probably NO.

think of it as no different than the signal1 and signal2 variables. The reason you have signal1 and signal2 in the Read method definition of the Interface is because they are part of the contract and mandatory for every implementation of the interface to use as inputs.

But ISettings sounds like something that a particular implementation would need whereas some others won't. (like Loggers, CacheManagers, Repositories etc.)

So you're right and more often than not, Approach #1 will be preferable. It keeps the interfaces clean & confined to the exact contractual input/outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is what I was thinking about - if I am using interfaces it is among other reasons to reduce coupling. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Thorough study of system requirment solves many problems and helps you design the application with more confidence. So first, think more and more until you reach a point when you can argue and reason about what you're going to do.

Secondly IMHO, the both approaches are OK. The first one as 'raja' pointed out is clean and succient and I don't repeat what he says again. But consider this situation: if later the `IDriver` implementors somehow need to be configured. Then passing some sort of setting to them solves many problems. Even if at the current moment you think it is unneccessary (and I admit it is what [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle says), you can provide empty setting ([NullObject pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)):

```
public Driver : IDriver
{
   public bool Read(ISettings settings, uint[] signal1, uint[] signal2)
   {
      if (settings.PreventSomeThing)
      {
         .....
      }

   }
}

public NullSetting : ISetting
{
   public bool PreventSomething = false;   
   ....
}
```